# Creating simple extension that runs JS on click

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Normally I run JS from console, but it's annoying, so I wanted to create a simple Chrome Extension, that would run it for me. Ideally without opening any additional popups, just by clicking the extension icon.

What I tried:

1. I created a folder with popup.html, popup.js, manifest.json, icon16.png, icon48.png and icon128.
2. For manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My Simple Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A simple Chrome extension to manipulate quiz elements.",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
      }
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    }
  }
```

3. For popup.js

```
document.getElementById('run-script').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
        function: runCode,
      });
    });
  });
  
  function runCode() {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][disabled]').forEach(function(radio) {
        radio.removeAttribute('disabled');
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.is-selected').forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.remove('is-selected');
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function(radio) {
        radio.checked = false;
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function(radio) {
        radio.value = '';
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.wpProQuiz_answerIncorrect').forEach(function(element) {
      element.classList.remove('wpProQuiz_answerIncorrect');
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.wpProQuiz_answerCorrectIncomplete').forEach(function(element) {
      element.classList.remove('wpProQuiz_answerCorrectIncomplete');
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.wpProQuiz_answerCorrect').forEach(function(element) {
      element.classList.remove('wpProQuiz_answerCorrect');
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.wpProQuiz_incorrect').forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.display = 'none';
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.wpProQuiz_response').forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.display = 'none';
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.wpProQuiz_QuestionButton').forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.display = 'block';
    });
  }
```

4. For popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      button {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="run-script">Run Script</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

1. After installing extension, when I click the icon. The button appears, but when I click on it, nothing happens and the console throws the following warning:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://kurzy.aeroweb.cz/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/bundle.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

2. Another thing. How would I change my JS, so it works on the icon click without opening popup with a button?

Comment: Remove default_popup and add a background service worker, use chrome.action.onClicked inside, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#injecting-a-content-script-on-click).

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped! Everything almost works. Some scripts are still ignored (work differently than from the console), but I'll figure it out later.

Answer (score 0):

As to answer below my question (thanks to wOxxOm), needed to replace the trigger with:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    files: ['content.js']
  });
});
```